# How to comment out multiple-llines comment in visaul-Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-c++

On Visual studio 2015 C++ compiler If I want to comment out multiple lines then I select them and press `CTRL + K CTRL + C` and to un-comment them `CTRL + K CTRL U`.

But when commenting them out the compiler sometimes comment them with `multiple-line comment` and sometimes comment them line by line:

```
/*int x;
x = 0;
cout << x << endl; */
```

And sometimes:

```
//int x;
//x = 0;
//cout << x << endl; */
```

With the same shortcut?!!

I want how to use the both notations. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872680/visual-studio-c-multiline-comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550156/comment-style-in-visual-studio-2017